# how do i make my website background a gradient colour?

Tags: html, css, header, dreamweaver, gradient

I am currently trying to create a website.

I have created the logo for the website but I'm not sure how to make my header and footer background a gradient color on Dreamweaver CS6.

I can only put it as a solid color and I am not sure if I need to use CSS or HTML to change it.

Does anyone know if it is possible, and if it is how to do it?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a online tool from which you can generate css gradient -

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

On left side of screen you have options to choose colors and on right you have code which you need to copy in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Try www.css3generator.com and then select gradient and select color and equivalent code will be generated ..copy the code and use in your CSS.
This site is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3:

```
  body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left, white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);
  }
```